# Unable to load an android-layout file as an anchor in Sceneform

Tags: android, android-layout, arcore, sceneform

I am in search of a working example that shows a layout file as an anchor, as the tutorial example (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/create-renderables) does not work for me.

I have tried to follow the first part of tutorial as given in the summary link to render a text view as an anchor, but it does not load any such layouts. On the other hand, I am able to load a sphere as an anchor (Using ShapeFactory class), but my end goal is to show anchors describing something about them.

My text view looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/planetInfoCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/abc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:text="Anchor"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
```

And the rendering code looks like:

```
 ViewRenderable.builder()
  .setView(arFragment.getContext(),R.layout.anchor_layout)
  .build()
  .thenAccept(r -> nodeRenderable = r)
  .exceptionally(throwable -> { Toast toast =
                    Toast.makeText(arFragment.getContext(), "Unable to load 
                    renderable.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return null;});
 anchorNode.setRenderable(nodeRenderable);
 anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

I am able to see a circular shadow when I am trying to load the Textview. Can anyone help me in that? Or anyone has a working example of loading a layout as an anchor?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Node, set its renderable to the ViewRenderable, and set its parent to the anchor.

```
val node = Node()
node.renderable = viewRenderable
node.parent = anchorNode
```